# Moment Number of months different

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Tying to work out the number of months different between two dates.

```
 let start = moment(latestDateAvailable.Date);
      console.log("Start: ", start);
      let end = moment(dateToGet);
      console.log("End: ", end);
let duration = moment.duration(start.diff(end, 'months'));
      let m = duration.asMonths();
      console.log("Months: ", m);
```

[image]

Im expecting 1, but result is 0?

Answer (score 0):

That is how it is supposed to work. The difference between 21 February and 3 March is not a full month -- for that the second date would have to be 21 March.

See [momentjs documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

> By default, `moment#diff` will truncate the result to zero decimal places, returning an integer. If you want a floating point number, pass `true` as the third argument.

See what you get with that third argument set to `true`:

```js
var feb21 = moment([2018, 2, 21]),
    mar03 = moment([2018, 3,  3]),
    mar21 = moment([2018, 3, 21]);

console.log(mar03.diff(feb21, 'months', true)); // 0.41857
console.log(mar21.diff(feb21, 'months', true)); // 1
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The documentation continues:

> `moment#diff` has some special handling for month and year diffs. It is optimized to ensure that two months with the same date are always a whole number apart.
>
> So Jan 15 to Feb 15 should be exactly 1 month.
>
> Feb 28 to Mar 28 should be exactly 1 month.

Anything less will be truncated to zero.